# Prevent recursive function locking the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have a recursive function which is locking my browser while running.

While this function is running all my jquery commands are locked waiting for the function end.

What should I do to make this function asynchronous?

This function runs on document.ready

```
function SearchTrip() {
$.post("/extensions/searchtrip", {
        from: $("#from").val(),
        to: $("#to").val(),
        ddate: $("#ddate").val()
    },
    function (mReturn) {
        if (mReturn.fTotalAmount != '0,00') {
            var sAirline = '';
            if (mReturn.Airline)
                sAirline = ' pela ' + mReturn.Airline;
            $("#buscandoPassagens").hide();
        } else if (SearchTripAmount < 5) {
            SearchTripAmount++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                SearchTrip();
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $("#pNaoEncontrada").show();
        }
    },
    "json");
}
```

Comment: Why are you lauching it recursively?

Comment: use setTimeout for each recursed call.

Comment: Is `SearchTripAmount` a global variable? Are you sure it's incrementing?

Comment: Yes, SearchTripAmount  is global, I have a limit of this function running without return no result to me that is 5 times.

Hi Kasyx, I need run it recursively because the function need to call itself if the result is = 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it asynchronously just wrap everything with `setTimeout`:

```
function SearchTrip(){
    setTimeout( function() {
        //this is your $.post i just deleted 'content' to make answer easier to read
        $.post(); 
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I end the loop after I run the function 5 times with no result? I don't want to this function runs forever.